# Play a sound for a specific number of times in AVAudioPlayerNode in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

There is an option **numberofloops** in `AVAudioPlayer` which repeats a sound file for a specified number of times.

I have to implement this type of function in `AVAudioPlayerNode` and I found an option just to loop a sound file in an infinite number of times in a loop using the following code

> audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer, atTime: nil,
>   options:.Loops, completionHandler: nil)

Is it possible to repeatedly play a file in a fixed number of times like as `AVAudioPlayer`? Is there any code sample to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure if there is an option to do it however you can achieve this by creating a simple function like below.

```
func playBuffer(buffer,times) {
for (var i=1;i<=times;i++) {   
audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioFileBuffer)
}
}
```

and then you call the function like this

```
playBuffer(buffer,3) // to execute three times.
// or
playBuffer(buffer,1) // to execute one time.
```

p.s: This is almost like a pseudo code just to show the logic. you have to write it in swift.